# How do I distinguish exceptions that I threw from others?

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core

[Microsoft's Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions) say to use the predefined .NET exception types, and to throw exceptions instead of returning error codes. I want the catcher of the exception to distinguish between one that I manually threw and one that was thrown by either a dependency or an unexpected runtime error.

Is there any way to do this with the predefined exceptions beyond extensive string parsing?

I had been considering creating generic exceptions like

```
public abstract class AppException : Exception;
public class AppException<T> : AppException where T : Exception { ... }
```

so that I could

```
void DoTheThing(int input)
{
  // run some code, including invoking stuff from 3rd party libraries,
  // but there may be problems that trigger their own ArgumentException
  // that have nothing to do with the input.
  // I could try/catch, but I do not want to log or process it here.

  if (invalidInput)
  {
    throw new AppException<ArgumentException>();
  }

  // run more code; again, I don't want to have to try/catch
  // unexpected ArgumentExceptions and log/process it.
}

try
{
  DoTheThing(inputInt);
}
catch (AppException<InvalidOperationException> ex) { ... }
catch (AppException ex) { ... }
catch (Exception ex) { ... }
```

If I were to do this without custom types, and just `throw new InvalidOperationException()`, then I couldn't make that distinction, but it violates the Best Practice. Or am I being too pedantic about the direction to use the built-in exceptions? Or is there a way to determine that distinction that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Probably just an opinion, but you can create your own exception, and still make it inherit from some of the existing ones: `public class MyAppInvalidOperationException : InvalidOperationException;` This way you achieve both goals.

Comment: Argument exceptions or invalid operation exceptions are thrown when your coded logic is wrong. There is no gain only pain if you use your own types in these cases.

Comment: BTW best practise says: *Introduce a new exception class **only** when a predefined one doesn't apply.* and explicit mention `InvalidOperationException` and `ArgumentException`. You are not too pedantic but too lazy to read the whole best practise word by word ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo when catching exceptions, how do I distinguish between an `ArgumentException` that I manually threw, and an `ArgumentException` that was thrown by either the runtime or some 3rd party library?

Comment: What would be the expected benefit if you can distinguish them? You passed an argument to a method that is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The guidance I'd use when deciding on custom exceptions is: *"would I handle this custom exception differently from any other?"*

For example. Imagine we build an API endpoint that receives some JSON in a Post, and try parsing the JSON into our expected data type.

```cs
[Function(nameof(PostSomething))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseData> PostSomething([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "my-api/data")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    string posted = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    MyData data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyData>(posted); // Might cause JsonException
}
```

(NB there are easier ways to deserialise JSON from an Azure Fn endpoint - this is just to illustrate)

If the client has posted invalid JSON to our endpoint, then currently this would throw a `JsonException` which (if unhandled) would cause a 500 error in your API.

But instead, you really want to throw some sort of 400 error, to tell the client they sent invalid data.

So you might say: "fine, we'll catch all `JsonExceptions` in some middleware in our API, and convert them all to 400 responses"

This causes a problem. What if your code throws a `JsonException` for a *different* reason? Maybe you are reading your application config and that's broken. You would end up generating a 400 error for something that's not the client's fault.

This is where a custom exception type comes in. Changing the above code:

```cs
[Function(nameof(PostSomething))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseData> PostSomething([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "my-api/data")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    string posted = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    MyData data;

    try
    {
        data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyData>(posted);
    }
    catch (JsonException ex)
    {
        // If there's a JsonException then we know it's the fault of the client's data.
        throw new ClientSentBadDataException(jex);
    }
}
```

And then in your error handling middleware, or where you handle errors at a top level, you can cater for that exception type differently from any other `JsonException`.

E.g. in an Azure Function middleware handler:

```cs
public class ExceptionMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger<ExceptionMiddleware> _logger;

    public ExceptionMiddleware(ILogger<ExceptionMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);    
        }
        catch (ClientSentBadDataException bdex)
        {
            var response = (await context.GetHttpRequestDataAsync())?.CreateResponse();
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

            context.GetInvocationResult().Value = response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) // including any other cases of JsonException
        {
            // whatever else, e.g. log and re-throw.
        }
    }
```